# Proper way to propagate computed value on Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to use computed value by `@Input` properties

But propagating initial value is not work well.

https://plnkr.co/edit/1MMpOYOKIouwnNc3uIuy

I create `App` (root component with template driven form) and `NumComponent` (child component that just saving typed value) component.

When i pass attribute to `NumComponent` like `[useThree]="true"` then i want set default value '3' to `NumComponent`

But i can't find way without using `setTimeout`

Is there way to propagate initial value without setTimeout?

---

**Edited at 5/5**

App component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <form novalidate #form="ngForm">
        <app-num name="num" ngModel [useThree]="true"></app-num>
      </form>
      <pre>{{form.value | json}}</pre>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {}
```

NumComponent

```
export const NumValueAccessor = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => NumComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-num',
  template: `<input [(ngModel)]="num" type="text" (ngModelChange)="updateValue()" />`,
  providers: [NumValueAccessor]
})
export class NumComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  num = 0;

  // I want set literal number 3 to `num` property
  // when `useThree` is true.
  @Input() useThree = false;

  onChange = (_: any) => {};

  updateValue(num = this.num) {
    this.onChange(String(num));
  }

  writeValue(value: string): void {
    if (this.useThree) {
      /**********
       * ISSUE
       **********/
      // this code is not work. after code ran, `NumComponent` has
      // value 3 but AppComponent's internal FormComponent value
      // is '' (empty string)
      // this.num = 3;
      // this.updateValue(3);

      // ran code with `setTimeout` solve this problem. but
      // I don't want using setTimeout for this feature.
      // setTimeout(() => {
      //   this.num = 3;
      //   this.updateValue(3);
      // }, 0);

      // Is there any way to propagate computed initial value?
      this.num = 3;
      this.updateValue(3);

      /**********
       * ISSUE
       **********/

      this.useThree = false;
      return;
    }
    this.num = Number(value);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {}

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {}
}
```

It seems that parent component don't realize propagated value at initialization lifecycle time.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] *in the question itself*, **not only on a third-party site**.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I add relevant code with comments. and i maintain previous plunker link for who need to execute the demo. :)

Comment: Template-driven forms are asynchronous. `registerOnChange` function is executed after you call `this.updateValue` within `writeValue`. `NgModel` doesn’t add a form control synchronously — it does it in a microtask(`promise.then`). You can only wait by scheduling another microtask like this https://plnkr.co/edit/A4xBldIIj58fPFjzndEW?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have understood the problem fully, but one possible solution to what you are looking for could be

```
private _useThree = false;
@Input() set useThree(value: boolean) {
     this._useThree = value;
     if (this._useThree) {
         this.num = 3;
     }
}
```

This way, any time you want to set the value of the input `useThree` property from the parent component, you actually execute the code of the setter method defined above.

Comment: I moved value update code to the `useTree` setter but it also has same problem with previous one.